# Complement rules in statistics

Tags: probability

The probability of event $A$ happening at least once is $1 - P(\bar{A})$… where $\bar{A}$ means "not $A$". But what is the probability of $A$ happening at least twice? I am new in statistics, and don't understand the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General formula is in the scenario that we compute "at least" probabilities in caseis as follows: and we need to consider all the probabilities larger than the given probability.

${{n\choose{r}}} * P^ r * (1−P(\bar{A}))^{n-r}$

where

$n$ = number of trials

$r$ = number of specific event you wish to obtain

$p$ = probability that event will occur

$q$ = probability that event will **not** occur. it is $1-p$

In your case where $n =2$

we have

${{2\choose{1}}} * P* (1-P)$

Note, this is in case that the probabilities are independent from each other. Otherwise, it is much complicated to have a general formula.

Comment: Nowhere did the OP state the independence assumption you are at least implicitly making.  Relying on unstated assumptions, which are often not true, is no way to help the OP learn probability.

Comment: I gave you a chance to make clear the unjustified assumption you were implicitly making.  You did not do so.  You still can and should - better late than never.

Comment: I added the assumption that I made,

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend being explicit about what $A$ is and what it means for it to occur "at least twice".

Let's say $A$ is the event of rolling a 6 in a single fair dice toss. The probability of the event happening, $P(A)$, is $$P(A) = \frac{1}{6} = 1 - P(\bar{A})$$. There isn't a concept of this event happening "at least twice" the way we're defining it. $A$ either occurs or doesn't occur.

We could ask "What is the probability of rolling at least two 6's out of 10 rolls?" If we slightly change the meaning of $A$:

The number of 6's rolled out of 10 rolls. This is then $$P(A \geq 2) = 1 - P(A=0) - P(A=1)$$
where $P(A=0) = (\frac{5}{6})^{10}$ and $P(A=1) = 10 \times (\frac{1}{6})(\frac{5}{6})^9$.

So I think your intuition is correct, just need to be clear about what you mean by events and their occurrence.